# Like button not incrementing in sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to increment the number of likes on a post (say for *postid* 109) whenever I click Like.

I added a new column **likecount** and all values are 0 by default. They do not increment on clicking Like button.

I've tried a lot and searched for similar questions, but to no help.

**HTML**

```
<form method= POST >
    <input type=submit  value='' name=like  class=likebutton>  
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if($_POST['like']) {
    $sqlst = "UPDATE images SET `likecount` = `likecount`+1  WHERE `postid` = '109'";
    $rslt= mysqli_query($db2, $sqlst);
}
```

Comment: first check replace `if(isset($_POST["like"]))` and should check that you are getting inside of if condition by using `echo 'post'; exit;` on submit. also You should check **likecount column** dataType in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think query is failing because  `postid` is integer and you are adding string value. Also use `isset()` for checking `$_POST['like']`, isset will execute script only when `$_POST['like']` not empty  Kindly try following

```
if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
$sqlst = "UPDATE images SET `likecount` = likecount + 1  WHERE `postid` = 109";
$rslt= mysqli_query($db2, $sqlst);
}
```

Comment: @YashPawse I edited the code can you please check now.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Developer!! I had tried using 'isset', but it wasn't working. This works fine! Great job!

Comment: I think its single quotes around postid and likecount that are causing this not to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if(isset($_POST["like"]))
```

instead of

```
if($_POST['like'])
```

Comment: Thanks @D-Shih, this helped me partly! great job! :)